# How to access Google APIs link that is mentioned in the `selfLink` field of Backend Services of Load Balancers?

Tags: google-chrome, kubernetes, google-cloud-platform, oauth-2.0

I have backend-services that I describe using `gcloud backend-services describe <backend-service-name> --global`. It has a field called `selfLink` that points to a URL: https://www.googleapis.com/compute/v1/projects//global/backendServices/.

I need to access that link in order to know the name of the load balancer.

I am facing this error:

```
{
  "error": {
    "code": 401,
    "message": "Request is missing required authentication credential. Expected OAuth 2 access token, login cookie or other valid authentication credential. See https://developers.google.com/identity/sign-in/web/devconsole-project.",
    "errors": [
      {
        "message": "Login Required.",
        "domain": "global",
        "reason": "required",
        "location": "Authorization",
        "locationType": "header"
      }
    ],
    "status": "UNAUTHENTICATED",
    "details": [
      {
        "@type": "type.googleapis.com/google.rpc.ErrorInfo",
        "reason": "CREDENTIALS_MISSING",
        "domain": "googleapis.com",
        "metadatas": {
          "method": "compute.v1.BackendServicesService.Get",
          "service": "compute.googleapis.com"
        }
      }
    ]
  }
}
```

When I visit the [suggested link](https://developers.google.com/identity/sign-in/web/sign-in), it states Deprecation and the title is `Integrate Google Sign-in in your Application`. That is not what I want to perform. I just want myself to authenticate and visit the URL. Also, I am logged in the Gcloud console and that should have let me access the URL.

How do I access the URL?

Comment: `selfLink` is an identifier and not a URL. Google uses the URL format for a number of items. Another example is OAuth Scopes.